# buttons are lost after redirection of the page using ObservableCollection in windows phone 8 c#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, observablecollection

In my windows phone application I am creating dynamic buttons using `ObservableCollection` into a `btn_groupname_Click` event like below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;
using Microsoft.Phone.UserData;
using System.Windows.Media;
using Microsoft.Phone.Maps.Controls;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Collections;

namespace GetContacts
{
    public partial class createGroups : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        string buttonName = "";
        public ObservableCollection<Group> groupbtn;
        List<CustomContact> contact = new List<CustomContact>();
        List<CustomContact> listOfContact2 = new List<CustomContact>();
        //List<Group> buttons = new List<Group>(); 
        List<Button> buttons = new List<Button>();
        List<List<CustomContact>> lls = new List<List<CustomContact>>();
        public createGroups()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            groupbtn = new ObservableCollection<Group>();
        }

        private void btn_groupname_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (tb_groupname.Text != string.Empty)
            {
                groupbtn.Add(new Group { Name = tb_groupname.Text });
                buttonName = tb_groupname.Text;
                lb_groupofcontacts.DataContext = groupbtn;
                tb_groupname.Text = string.Empty;
            }
        }      
    }
}
```

And below is my `Group` class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;
using GetContacts.Resources;
using Microsoft.Phone.UserData;

namespace GetContacts
{
    public class Group
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Group()
        { 

        }
        public Group(Button btn)
        {
            Name = btn.Name;

        }
    }
}
```

Its working fine and create multiple buttons when I am working on the current page but when I go to the next page and after come back to the previous page the buttons are lost, How can I get these buttons after redirection of the page. Kindly suggest me. Waiting for your reply.
Thanks.

Comment: You need to save the transient state of your page and restore it when you navigate back to the said page. You should first understand the Application Execution Model. Here's a good place to start: http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2010/07/20/understanding-the-windows-phone-application-execution-model-tombstoning-launcher-and-more-part-3.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to maintain state of the collection through out your app You can take collection as `Static` data Member,

```
        public createGroups()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            if(groupbtn!== null)
            groupbtn = new ObservableCollection<Group>();
        }
public static ObservableCollection<Group> groupbtn;
```

Comment: have you set collection as itemsource in navigatedTo event ?

Comment: collection as itemsource means?

Comment: But I am not showing `obsevationcollection` into the listbox, I am use it to another.

Comment: so why have you used ObservableCollection ?